# Unity Accelerometer Documentation

Tags: unity-game-engine, normalization, accelerometer, timedelta

I have a question concerning the Input.acceleration command in Unity.

According to the official documentation a basic code is as follows :

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 10.0F;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
        dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(dir * speed);
    }
}
```

Why does it check if the Vector3 is more than 1 ? (dir.sqrMagnitude) and then set it to 1 ? 
Is that for optimisation ?

Also whats the purpose of multiplying it by deltatime ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

They are locking the increment of the direction to 1. Normally you can move on a axis between -1 to 1. At one you are going as fast as you can in one direction and -1 is as fast as possible in the opposite direction on that axis.

For your second question multiplying times delta time will give you a constant movement speed even if the frame rate is not constant. It makes your movement more consistent.

So if you want the on screen whatever to move faster you up your speed which should be publicly available in the properties in Unity design time. 20 speed should go much faster than 10 speed.

So an example of why they are doing this is lets say your acceleration is .5 you will get 1/2 the movement over the frame. But at 1 you will get the full delta * 10.